# Google Glass XE9 fails to find system update

Tags: google-glass

I have a pair of Google Glass with version XE9 installed. When I go to Settings > Version, the screen shows "XE9 up-to-date" and there seems to be no option for upgrade.

Is there any way to force Google Glass to update?

Comment: Just buy another pair today :)

Comment: If it hasn't updated since XE9, something has been up for awhile. Is your device rooted? Have you tried connecting it to wifi and leaving it plugged in for a few hours? Have you flashed any system images, like ones from here? https://developers.google.com/glass/tools-downloads/system

Comment: @JennyMurphy: I don't think my device is rooted. I've had it connected to wifi and plugged in for the whole night with no result. Should I attempt to flash it? I haven't done so yet.

Comment: @JohannesBrodwall I have the same problem now with XE12.1, did you find any solution working for you?

Comment: @ocramot I never found a solution. The Glass are no longer with me, but was given to a colleague.